# JavaScript Working When Access From Internet But Not Responding When Access Page From Folder Assets On WebView Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, assets

I try to access this page url : [DEMO FACE TRACKER](http://auduno.github.io/clmtrackr/clm_image.html) using android webview. And I using this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    wv.loadUrl("http://auduno.github.io/clmtrackr/clm_image.html");
}
```

and IT WORKS!

But when I copy all of page (include javascript) to local, and access it form assets folder then app return NOT RESPONDING.

this is code that I use to access local assets:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```

For information, all of assets (scripts, css, etc) except media has combined into single page and when I access from browser (on my computer) its working, but not in android webview.

whether on android has special permission for this? please help :) thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have pathing issue. It might not be loading from where you think it does. Try adding to see

```
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String resUrl) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, resUrl);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Loading " + resUrl);
        }
```

Add setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs to address javascript security issue when loading from file.

```
wv.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

Comment: I was combine all of external files (javascript, css, etc) to single file "index.html" and it working if I access from Internet, but not in local asset folder of android...

Comment: Try  wv.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

Comment: hi @roostertech, thank you for your solution to add this line "wv.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);", and it works!